# JAXB Resteasy marshall desired fields

Tags: jaxb, marshalling, resteasy

I would like to marshall an object using JAXB, the problems is that I would like to marshall just some fields depending on some business logic. For example I have an object like this:

```
Class Foo{
private name;
private details;
private url;

//Getter and setter methods
```

}

What I want to achieve is send a JSON response with just the name and url field, like 
{name:"someName",url:"myUrl"}, so that when clients needs to retrieve more info they could request the uri sent in the URL field, and JAXB will marshall the details field this time.
{name:"someName",url:"myUrl",details:"details"}.

I know I could use a wrapper class for that, but It's kindda annoying to write wrapper classes for the same pieces of data. So I was wondering if there's a way to configure JAXB to marshall just some fields. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

By default JAXB will just marshal the properties that have values.  This should give you the behaviour that you want.

```
Foo foo = new Foo();
foo.setName("Jane Doe");
marshaller.marshal(foo, System.out);  // results in <foo><name>Jane Doe</name></foo>
foo.setDetails("Some Details");
marshaller.marshal(foo, System.out);  // results in <foo><name>Jane Doe</name><details>Some Details</details></foo>
```